# Query returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    F2_FILIAL, F2_SERIE, F2_DOC, 
    C6_NUM, AB7_NUMOS, A1_NOME, F2_EMISSAO, F2_VALBRUT, F2_VEND1, 
    A3_NOME,F2_COND , E4_DESCRI, C5_NATUREZ, ED_DESCRIC, AAG_DESCRI
FROM 
    SF2010 SF 
LEFT JOIN 
    SE4010 SE ON F2_COND = E4_CODIGO 
LEFT JOIN 
    SA3010 A3 ON F2_VEND1 = A3_COD 
LEFT JOIN 
    SA1010 A1 ON F2_CLIENTE = A1_COD 
LEFT JOIN 
    SD2010 SD ON F2_DOC = D2_DOC 
LEFT JOIN 
    SC6010 C6 ON D2_PEDIDO = C6_NUM 
LEFT JOIN 
    SC5010 C5 ON D2_PEDIDO = C5_NUM 
LEFT JOIN 
    SED010 ED ON C5_NATUREZ = ED_CODIGO 
LEFT JOIN 
    AB7010 AB ON SUBSTRING(C6_NUMOS,1,6) = AB7_NUMOS 
LEFT JOIN 
    AAG010 AG ON AB7_CODPRB = AAG_CODPRB 
WHERE 
    (F2_CLIENTE >= '      ' 
     AND F2_CLIENTE <= 'zzzzzz') 
    AND (F2_EMISSAO >= '20170222'
         AND F2_EMISSAO <= '20170222')
    AND (F2_VEND1 >= '' 
         AND F2_VEND1 <= 'zz') 
    AND (C5_NATUREZ >= '' 
         AND C5_NATUREZ <= 'zzzzzzzzzz') 
    AND (F2_COND >= '' 
         AND F2_COND <= 'zzz') 
    AND (F2_FILIAL >= '' 
         AND F2_FILIAL <= 'zz') 
    AND (SF.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*') 
    AND F2_DUPL <> '' 
    AND F2_VALFAT <> 0 
ORDER BY 
    F2_VEND1, F2_EMISSAO
```

And it results in something like this:

[image: query result]

Notice that the 2 last rows are the same (the main field here is F2_DOC, it should never appear twice), but since the field C6_NUM and AB7_NUMOS has more than one reference it displays both of them, duplicating the row.

How can I improve my query to not duplicate a row when the table I'm joining has more than 1 distinct FK to the table I'm querying?

Comment: Column `AB7_NUMOS` has different value.  That's why it displays 2 rows. Exclude the unnecessary column.

Comment: First you must decide what you need. There are two values in AB7_NUMOS: 009851 and 009854.
Wich one you want? the latest? the Greatest?... That realy depends on your business specifications.

Comment: @Eric Yes, it has different values, but this column is necessary. The ideal output would be: if it has more than one value, show only the first.

Comment: You can use `MAX(AB7_NUMOS)`.  In this case, it will show 009854 since it has higher value.

Comment: @MárioGarcia Define "first"?

Comment: @underscore_d the smaller number, I tried changing the AB7_NUMOS to MAX(AB7_NUMOS) but I get:

`Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'SF2010.F2_FILIAL' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Yes, any columns/expressions that are not aggregated need to be in a `group by` clause. Alternatively you could use a subquery to get the `top 1` row by whichever criteria you choose.

Comment: @underscore_d could you demonstrate such subquery?

Comment: ok, let's say I need the greatest number, but how and where should I make this choice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing multiple left joins and the leftest table in the join doesn't have ( or not mentioned in select ) a unique value, it's possible you get duplicate rows. if you need to have a unique column, use the primary key in the leftest table inside the select statement or add a column like 
    row_number() as id
to your query.